# Can you order attachments in an e-mail so that the receiver receives them in the same order?

Tags: email-attachments

We're considering using an external application to send e-mails where the attachments have huge filesizes.

One of our users states the requirement: **it must be possible to ORDER attachments**, so that I can refer to them as "the first attachment", "the second attachment" and the receiver will see the attachments in the same order I sent them.

She claims any normal email clients support this: the sender chooses the order, the recipients client always shows the attachments in this order.

I can't verify that claim. Is this true? Is it stated anywhere? **How (technically) are attachments ordered?**

Answer (score 0):

Well... Inside the message there is order. Attachments are sent sequentially one-after-the-other inside MIME text. But RFC makes no statement on how these should be displayed in email client. And it even might depend on your email generating software to keep the order you added the attachments in (JavaMail does so)

Things you could consider:

- Prefix your attachment filenames with a number `1_first_attachment.txt` `2_contract.pdf` and so on.
- Use HTML for your emails and create a section "attachments: a, b, c" with linkd to the attachments using Content-ID (href="cid:xxx")

Answer (score 0):

Actual, when u load the document to the email, and load next, they gonna be in order anyway. They not gonna be mixed. 
if u afraid that particular ur email gonna mix attachments, just add numerical order) 
[This is example where i just adding files. I just by holding shift click on the files in that order that i wanted and that is all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEyHL.png)

[And i receive this message with attachments in the same order as it was sent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A4NL.png)